# C++ Strings adding at the start and at the end

Tags: c++, string

I want to add a `^` at the start of the string and a `$` at the end.

```
std::string s1 (".V/.B/.R/");
```

Is the best way to use ?

```
s1.append(s1.begin(),"^");
s1.append(s1.end(),"$");
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? Performance? Clearness?

Comment: Performance really would be good if it was clear to @leftaroundabout

Comment: Thinking about it, the nice way `"^" + strValue + "$"` does, at least in C++11 (thanks to move semantics), probably not even have significantly worse performance than C-style manual memory allocation, so I'd definitely go with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be `insert` rather than `append`, but otherwise it seems ok.

An even easier way would be

```
s1 = '^' + s1 + '$';
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use [`std::string::append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) in that way:

```
s1.insert(0, "^");
s1.append("$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your examples won't work as they don't use any of the `stl::string::append` [overloads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/), you can create a new string and add the elements individually, i.e.

```
std::string FormatText( const std::string& rstrInput )
{
    std::string strOutput = "^"; 
    strOutput += rstrInput ;
    strOutput += "$";
    return strOutput;    // RVO will eliminate copying
}
```

But there are probably a number of ways of doing this, appending is probably the simplest.

```
std::string strResult = "^" + strValue + "$";
```

You could also use stringstreams..

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "^" << strValue  << "$";
std::string strResult = ss.str();
```

... printf style string formation etc etc..

Comment: what no mention of the `insert` that was his probable intent?